# How can i remove slug in custome post type url?

Tags: wordpress, url, wordpress-theming, slug, permalinks

In listings theme by Woothemes, the child them Bookclub.
when I add a book - as a custom post type - the url become as following :

```
mysite/book/post-name
```

I tried to remove the slug "book" but i failed
I want it to be

```
mysite/post-name
```

Answer (score 4):

Much better then installing a whole plugin for this.
Tested with 4.3:

```
register_post_type( 'dummy', array(
    //other custom posttype definitions 
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/')
) );
```

After this **save your rewrite rules** to make it work.

Comment: This is much cleaner than installing an entire plugin, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it was quite easy, install the plugin "Remove slug from custom post type" to remove the '/product/' slug, no settings required. Install the plugin "SEO Ultimate" to remove the 'product-category' slug, in SEO Ultimate settings under 'Permalink Tweaker' check the 'Product Categories' and save. We use it for affiliates so cannot comment on other areas such as cart.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how well this plugin works, but here you go.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/